# Unable install npm on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I'm facing an issue while installing npm.

I'm trying to run angular app on my server, for that I'm trying to install nodejs and npm but I'm unable to install npm.

First, I have to install npm "3.10.10" then in removed npm.

For uninstalling I tried this command "sudo npm uninstall npm -g"

```
sudo apt install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
```

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I followed below link for installing nodejs

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

```
node -v
v6.11.4
```

```
npm
The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install npm
```

Even i have tried below option also:

```
    sudo curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100  6255  100  6255    0     0   4995      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  4992
    tar=/bin/tar
    version:
    tar (GNU tar) 1.28
    Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later .
    This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

    Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
    install npm@latest
    fetching: https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-5.5.1.tgz
    module.js:471
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/npm.15884/package/bin/read-package-json.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
        at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
        at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
        at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
    up to date in 0.076s
    npm ERR! path ../../../tmp/npm.15884/package
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! errno -13
    npm ERR! syscall symlink
    npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../../../tmp/npm.15884/package' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm'
    npm ERR!     at Error (native)
    npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../../../tmp/npm.15884/package' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm'
    npm ERR!     at Error (native)
    npm ERR!   cause: 
    npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../../../tmp/npm.15884/package' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm'
    npm ERR!        at Error (native)
    npm ERR!      errno: -13,
    npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
    npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',
    npm ERR!      path: '../../../tmp/npm.15884/package',
    npm ERR!      dest: '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm' },
    npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink \'../../../tmp/npm.15884/package\' -> \'/usr/lib/node_modules/npm\'\n    at Error (native)',
    npm ERR!   errno: -13,
    npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
    npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
    npm ERR!   path: '../../../tmp/npm.15884/package',
    npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm' }
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/kanna/.npm/_logs/2017-10-23T12_05_15_229Z-debug.log
    It failed
```

I have uninstalled npm and tried multiple times to install npm.

Comment: which ubuntu version you are using ?

Comment: try using NVM i'll manage npm and node versions for you and it installs in the home directory so the earlier installation won't matter

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: When you install node on Ubuntu I'm pretty sure you also get npm automatically. So something is going wrong there... can you show what happens when you install Node.js using the commands provided on the node.js webpage?

Comment: VtrKanna, uninstall nodejs and then reinstall nodejs. Check syslogs for errors. Try node 8.x isntead of 6.x and see if you still get the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
Your issue is clearly a permission problem, I'm not sure who setup up your machine or how. But your user is not in the sudoers group, which is why you're getting that error. Try fixing your permissions and then run the commands above.

Comment: What is python software properties? What is different about this than the instructions on https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/ under Debian and Ubuntu ?

Comment: It allows the script/user who installs it to more easily install new PPAs
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/What-s-python-software-properties-necessary-for-td5043683.html

Comment: error: sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Comment: Yeah, I read that but I still don't understand what PPA is or how you get anything newer from the same url, was hoping you had a better explanation

Comment: @CodyG. Here's what a PPA is: https://askubuntu.com/a/4987/743407.
Also that same URL was never run by the OP, they installed node via the default Ubuntu PPA package, which is older and might be confusing when you're getting strange errors trying to run more bleeding edge node code.

Comment: @VtrKanna Your system is clearly in a state of disarray for you to be getting and error like that. I would look around for better suited answers for an issue of such caliber.
Here's a good place to start: (Don't follow the first guy's suggestions, and also make sure this isn't simply an issue running sudo on your end): https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set

Comment: @VtrKanna Upon further inspection your problem is permissions oriented, the error is from you not having root access.

Comment: @SeedyROM thanks for the ubuntu question link, that gave me a much better perspective, also OP did say they followed the node.js directions with that distro, but I think you found the issue of not being sudoer